# Extracting data from two dataframes to create a third

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using Python Pandas for the following. I have three dataframes, `df1`, `df2` and `df3`. Each has the same dimensions, index and column labels. I would like to create a fourth dataframe that takes elements from `df1` or `df2` depending on the values in `df3`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=list('0123'), columns=['A', 'B'])

df1

Out[67]: 
      A         B
0  1.335314  1.888983
1  1.000579 -0.300271
2 -0.280658  0.448829
3  0.977791  0.804459

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=list('0123'), columns=['A', 'B'])
df2
Out[68]: 
      A         B
0  0.689721  0.871065
1  0.699274 -1.061822
2  0.634909  1.044284
3  0.166307 -0.699048

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 0, 1], 'B': [1, 0, 1, 0]})
df3
Out[69]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  0  1
3  1  0
```

The new dataframe, `df4`, has the same index and column labels and takes an element from `df1` if the corresponding value in `df3` is `1`. It takes an element from `df2` if the corresponding value in `df3` is a `0`.

I need a solution that uses generic references (e.g. `ix` or `iloc`) rather than actual column labels and index values because my dataset has fifty columns and four hundred rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your DataFrames happen to be numeric, and the selector matrix happens to be of indicator variables, you can do the following:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(
    df1.as_matrix() * df3.as_matrix() + df1.as_matrix() * (1 - df3.as_matrix()),
    index=df1.index,
    columns=df1.columns)
```

I tried it by me and it works. Strangely enough, @Yakym Pirozhenko's answer - which I think is superior - doesn't work by me as well.

Comment: You method works. There is a small typo in the second part of the formula but the sytax does the job. Thanks                       pd.DataFrame(
    df1.as_matrix() * df3.as_matrix() + df2.as_matrix() * (1 - df3.as_matrix()),
    index=df1.index,
    columns=df1.columns)

Answer (score 1):

`df4 = df1.where(df3.astype(bool), df2)` should do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size = (4,2)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size = (4,2)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size = (4,2)))
df4 = df1.where(df3.astype(bool), df2)

print df1, '\n'
print df2, '\n'
print df3, '\n'
print df4, '\n'
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  0  3
1  8  8
2  7  4
3  1  2 

   0  1
0  7  9
1  4  4
2  0  5
3  7  2 

   0  1
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  1  1
3  1  0 

   0  1
0  7  9
1  8  4
2  7  4
3  1  2
```

Comment: This solution returns a copy of df2 in df4, i.e. df4 is identical with df2 instead of extracting elements from df1 and df2 depending on values in df3

Comment: Let me know if this works. I edited in the boolean mask explicitly.

Comment: Hi @Yakym - it still does not work. df4 is same as df2

Comment: This seems to work for me on python2.7.9 and pandas0.17.1

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I think this is a good answer, but, strangely enough, it is not working by me as well, FYI.

Comment: I like yours. I wonder why the use of `.where` is not reproducible. Perhaps try using `.apply` in place of `.astype`?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I have the same version of Python but pandas 1.15.2-12, which might be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm upvoting this as this is the right approach - hope we eventually figure out why this wasn't working on all systems.